# How to create a Hibernate POJO with a data member mapping to a column which is not unique

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

```
I have 2 tables : Employee and Department (many to one relationship)

My pojos look like this: 

@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
class Employee {

@Id
private String employeeId;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "department", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "university_id"))
private Department department;

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
class Department {

@Id
private String deptId;

private String universityId;

}
```

So basically when the Employee object loads/get, it should load its data member Department using the university_id (may not be unique) for the join and not its primary key dept_id. How can I do this using annotations?

I am new to hibernate.please let me know what do I need to do.Problem in summary: How to load an object using any of its columns other than its primary key or unique column from another POJO ?

Answer (score 0):

OneToMany, ManyToOne semantics are for primary-foreign key. You are trying to join two tables on another column rather than foreign this is not good,

I would rather use inner join with where clause. 
In pure sql it would have been.

```
select * from Employee e inner join Department d on e.employeeId = d.deptId where universityId = ?
```

HQL

```
from Employee e inner join fetch e.department d where d.universityId = ?
```

Your ids are not numeric strange a bit.

You can use criteria builder or named query to perform you query.
Today you want to restrict search on university id tomorrow it may be another column, you cannot keep on doing this with annotations. The annotation mappers are not meant for this.

Hope this helps.